# What does the /apps/indicator-sound/volume_mute GConf key do?

Tags: 10.10, indicator, settings, gconf, volume-control

What does the `/apps/indicator-sound/volume_mute` GConf key do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When checked, the volume is muted by default when you log in.

[image]

Comment: DoR, this does not appear to work on my system. I'm running 10.04. I set volume to halfway with volume_mute off and reboot: after login, volume is set to halfway and unmuted. I leave the volume at halfway and set volume_mute on and reboot: after login, volume is still set to halfway and unmuted. Does this work for you?

Comment: @skyblue he's on 11.04, so your system may work a bit differently.